# ¿Por que no funciona el timer?

Tags: java, programacion-asincrona

No entiendo por que no me funciona el timer, quiero que una vez pasados 3 segundos se cierre la ventana

```
private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    char clave[] = txtPass.getPassword();
    String pass = new String(clave);

    if (txtUsuario.getText().equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin")) {
        lblResultado.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblResultado.setText("Acceso correcto");
       Timer timer = new Timer(3000, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        });
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        lblResultado.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblResultado.setText(" Usuario o contraseña invalidos. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! supongo que esto es java? y estas creando un timer dentro de un metodo.. se acaba el metodo, se acaba el timer sin siquiera arrancar...

Comment: Si el método para cerrar la ventana es `this.dispose()`, entonces te ha faltado meterlo en la función lambda que estás pasando al Timer. Intercambia la línea de `});` con la de `this.dispose();` y te funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de llamar dentro el proceso que deseas realizar, en este caso cerrar la ventana con `dispose()`:

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(3000, (ActionEvent e) -> {

        this.dispose();

        });
```

También puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.dispose();
  }
});
```